# .htaccess redirect for all files but with exceptions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I know this has been asked thousands times, but I've been googling for three hours without any result. So I'm asking here. I'm creating a website. All the content is in the folder /subfolder. Now I want to redirect all the requests to another domain (let's say domain.com), at the exception of the files that I actually use. It may seem weird but it makes sense in my situation. So what I have at the moment is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^account$ account.php
RewriteRule ^home$ myhome.php
RewriteRule ^options$ options.php
RewriteRule ^login$ login.php
RewriteRule ^links$ editlinks.php
RewriteRule ^help$ howto.php
RewriteRule ^$ index.php
RewriteRule ^forgot$ forgot.php
RewriteRule ^r$ redirect.php
RewriteRule ^r/(.*)$ redirect.php?id=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(login.php|login)
RewriteRule (.*) external.php?parameter=$1 [L]
```

How can I do this ? the above code always redirects me to domain.com.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the `myhome` stuff for? are these all the rules that you have?

Comment: I have actually a lot more. The myhome is not to show an ugly .php URL. I have /account, /myhome, /options, /help and now /account.php /myhome.php, /options.php, /howto.php...

Comment: https://amitoverflow.com/2021/05/01/redirect-domain-with-exception/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to place redirect just below `RewriteEngine On` and use `THE_REQUEST` instead of `REQUEST_URI` like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/media [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(login|signup)(\.php)?[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^home$ myhome.php [L]
RewriteRule ^links$ editlinks.php [L]
RewriteRule ^help$ howto.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(account|login|options|forgot)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^r$ redirect.php [L]
RewriteRule ^r/(.+)$ redirect.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Well, it still doesn't work. For all URLs I try, it redirects me to domain.com.
Try out by yourself, on http://thomaskowalski.net/steamlinks/login.php for example

Comment: Updated it. Now it only (should) work for login and login.php, but you've got the idea.

Comment: Oh this is so cool. Like really thanks so much. Now I've got a last question (I don't want to ask you too much but), I've got a media directory in my current directory, how can I do to make the content of it not redirected ? I tried this :
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(login|signup|myhome|home|links|help|r|external.php|style.css|javascript.js|media)?[?\s] [NC]

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Thank you very, very much. I don't know how to express how grateful I am to you. Thank you, really :) now everything's fine, I hope I'll have learnt from this